# how to get specific item that selected?

Tags: angularjs

- screenshot attached.

I learning angularJS. 
And i can't find a way to remove the selected item that the 'Remove' button was click on.

Is there any way to do it ?

code attached:

```
        <ul class="unstyled">
            <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
                <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.text}}</span>
                <button class="btn" ng-click="removeTodo()">Remove</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

[image]

Comment: How about passing the todo item into your `removeTodo()` method, then in that method (I assume in an associated controller), remove that item from your list.

Comment: ok .. how to do it ? :( i just starting learn .. can't find a way )

Comment: So, in the `ng-repeat` you have the `todo` object, so in your `ng-click` you can have `removeTodo(todo)`. Then in your `removeTodo` method, you then have the selected `todo` object and maybe find the index of the item in your array of objects, `todos`, and splice it out. That bit is just standard JavaScript rather than anything specifically Angular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module("app" , []);
app.controller("MyCtrl" , function($scope){
  
  $scope.todos = [
    {"text" :"Learn AngularJS","done":false},{"text" :"build an app","done":false}];
  
  $scope.removeTodo = function(index) {
    $scope.todos.splice(index,1);
    
    }
  
  $scope.removeTodo2 = function(todo) {
    var index = getByValue( $scope.todos,todo);
    $scope.todos.splice(index,1);
    
    }
  
  $scope.addTodo = function(todo){
    var toDoObject = {"text":todo,"done":false};
    $scope.todos.push(toDoObject);
    
  };
  
  $scope.done = function(todo){
    angular.forEach($scope.todos,function(index,todo1){
        if(todo == todo1)
           $scope.todos[index].done = !$scope.todos[index].done;
      })
   
    
    }
  
  function getByValue(arr, value) {

  for (var i=0, iLen=arr.length; i<iLen; i++) {

    if (arr[i].text == value) return i;
  }
}
  
  });
```

```css
.done{
  text-decoration: line-through;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  
 <ul class="unstyled">
            <li ng-repeat="todo in todos track by $index">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done" >
                <span ng-class="{'done' : todo.done == true}">{{todo.text}}</span>
                <button class="btn" ng-click="removeTodo($index)">Remove</button>
               <button class="btn" ng-click="removeTodo2(todo.text)">Remove2</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
  <input type="text" ng-model="todo">
  <input type="button" ng-click = "addTodo(todo)" value="Add">
  
  </div>
```

Comment: @Yanshof i edit my answer. please if work for u accept it. thanks.

Comment: Yeah I guess passing in the `$index` is much better.

Comment: But don't pass `$index` if using any filters ... won't be correct index. Safer to do your own indexing

Comment: @Yanshof I update my answer and add removeTodo2 that delete by todo value and text-decoration css to it.